# Threaded console app not exiting upon completion

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services

I wrote an integration program that fetches data from an ERP and sends it to another program via a SOAP API.

In order to determine which data needs to be updated or created I'm also fetching the data from the SOAP API and building some custom early bound entities with that data using

```
records.AsParallel().ForAll(record =>
{
    var acc = new Account(connection, record.name_value_list);
    accountList.Add(acc);
});
Task.WaitAll();
```

I'va added the last instruction after having seen that the programs hangs upon completion and I have to close it manually (and it still lags 5-10 seconds when I do it).

I tried to add an additional wait condition in my Main as the last operation, but it does not help.

I debugged the app and in the Thread panel I see this:

[image: Thread panel in VS]

How can I manage to exit my application gracefully?

Comment: Quick question, for `accountList.Add`, is that class a `List<T>`? If so you are going to run in to major problems because `List<T>` is not thread safe.

Comment: it's of type ConcurrentBag

Comment: I don't know C# but in most languages you have join your child threads when they finish work.  Looks like C# has a join function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the task completed? You might try passing a CancelationToken and send a CancelationRequest and catch the OperationCanceledException with a MessageBox.Show()...If it gets canceled then the task never completes and something is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: I was retrieving the data from the ERP via a C++ DLL Api, but I was missing the closing of the connection at completion.

Once I did that the program closed correctly.